# Perform CRUD operation in Jmeter in Sequence

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario of Creating 10 objects, Reading the 10, Updating and Deleting the same objects.
I am using a CSV file for the request,test data, response verification. 
I will be receiving a token on creating a object, and am i have no idea on how to store the tokens of 10 created objects and use the same token for GET,UPDATE and DELETE operations.

Note : I have tried to store single token in a variable but am not aware of storing multiple variables and accessing them.

Need inputs on this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Functions and Variables User Manual Chapter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So if you extract some value into a JMeter Variable in setUp Thread Group and plan to refer it from the other Thread Group(s) you need to convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)

See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for more details if needed

Comment: Yes, I have used the same concept for Setup and other thread groups, my question is, I need to perform the CRUD operation within the same thread group with the details as mentioned in the question